# Kmail not sending mail

Tags: mail, smtp, kmail

I am asking this here because I could not find a solution anywhere on the web.

KMail can currently receive my email but will not send any (either to mailing lists or to a regular address)

The error it gives me is:

"5.7.1 Rejected due to unmatching envelope and header sender."

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

Actually, the issue is that KMail has a somewhat confusing (at least to me) distinction between identities and email accounts. So my main identity was a gmail one, but I was trying to send (with unified inboxes) an email from a different server altogether.

I found out that this was the culprit after setting up Kmail in another machine. Since it was new I did not import the account from Thunderbird, I just set everything up from scratch, and did not retain a default gmail identity. I did not have any issues in this new install, and therefore I assume this was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed this issue by setting the SMTP Authentication to XOAUTH2 from default PLAIN.

Goto Settings >> Configure Kmail... >> Accounts
Switch to "Sending" tab. Select the entry for smtp.gmail.com
MOdify and in Advanced tab change "Authentication" option value to XOAUTH2.

Answer (score 1):

I had an email alias inserted in my Identity. Removing that solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Office 365 account, make sure that your outgoing server is set as "Microsoft Exchange Server (EWS) transport agent". For that, go to Settings > Configure KMail... > Accounts > Sending. You should see the former in the "Type" column. If you don't, add a new account for outgoing server, and follow the steps in the respective [KMail wiki article](https://userbase.kde.org/Kmail/Configuring_Kmail/Accounts/Office_365#Outgoing_server).

I tried everything from this post to no avail, and this fixed my issue. It looks like I (or KMail automatically) had set up an SMTP outgoing account by mistake, and then no matter what I did, I couldn't send any mail at all. Credit goes to [emptythevoid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-dkD92r3FE).